# Unable to follow Feynman Lectures reading on opacity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

Feynman is explaining the phenomenon of opacity in terms of classical electrodynamics.

> Let us first ask: “What is an opaque screen?” Suppose we have a completely opaque screen between a source S and an observer at P, as in Fig. 31–6(a). If the screen is “opaque” there is no field at P. Why is there no field there? According to the basic principles we should obtain the field at P as the field Es of the source delayed, plus the field from all the other charges around. But, as we have seen above, the charges in the screen will be set in motion by the field Es, and these motions generate a new field which, if the screen is opaque, must exactly cancel the field Es on the back side of the screen. You say: “What a miracle that it balances exactly! Suppose it was not exactly right!” If it were not exactly right (remember that this opaque screen has some thickness), the field toward the rear part of the screen would not be exactly zero. So, not being zero, it would set into motion some other charges in the material of the screen, and thus make a little more field, trying to get the total balanced out. So if we make the screen thick enough, there is no residual field, because there is enough opportunity to finally get the thing quieted down.

Here is the [source](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html) (with diagram, which I can't embed here for some reason).

I want to understand this entirely from the perspective of electromagnetic fields and charges (for example, the concept of "photon" hasn't yet been introduced).

I lose Feynman at "trying to get the total balanced out." Why is it necessarily the case that additional electrons moving will cause the field to be canceled out on the far side of the screen? For example, I could imagine a case where the resonance induced by the wave amplifies the existing wave and it comes out the other side at double strength.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A really thin piece of the material reducing the field is what it means for the material to be opaque.

To see why it at the very least does not amplify the wave, we can look to conservation of energy. To get the charge moving, the field offloads some energy into the charge, and in turn the moving charge produces EM waves. However, the charge can't produce more EM energy than what was offloaded, so in the worst case, the EM field will simply pick back up the energy it lost. For an opaque material, it just happens that this goes in the other direction, where energy is lost to the material (or perhaps reflected).

Comment: "is what it means for the material to be opaque" — fair enough! But this leads me to wonder why most objects are opaque. Is this not rather a special thing to happen?

Comment: @EliRose It being impossible to gain energy means it is only possible for the EM field to lose energy in this. So in all likelihood, we're going to see a loss. On a more gritty level, you can look at a 'charge on a spring' notion (with inspiration from electrons in atoms) and a 'free charge' notion (like in conductors). The first has room for being opaque and the second will always be opaque.